# Python builtins.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

When I download one module in PyCharm, I can glance over the code in the `.py` file. For example, I can find the code in `re.py` to know more about the method. But when I want to know something about the methods about list, I find the `builtins.py`. It's a pity that 'pass' instead of the details.

```
def abs(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
""" Return the absolute value of the argument. """
pass
```

I know some methods do with C. Can you tell me what should I do to find the code in the document?

Comment: Search it online ?

Comment: Those functions are implemented in C (to be faster) and not in Python, which is why there is no way to see the details in Python code. Follow the above link to find out how to see the C implementation.

Comment: OK,I know it now.Thank you.